# Change title for dynamically created php pages

Tags: php, title

I have just one index.php file that generates the other pages using:

```
RewriteRule ^page 1.php$ index.php?cat=a [NC]
RewriteRule ^page 2.php$ index.php?cat=b [NC]
```

I'm trying to use the following code to change the title of my pages but it's working just for index.php.

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if(isset($page)) {
switch($page) {
case "/index.php":
$title = "this is homepage";
break;
case "/page 1.php":
$title = "products";
break;
case "/page 2.php":
$title = "services";
break;
}
}else{
$title = "default title";
}

print "<title>$title</title>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you echoed $page before? Perhaps the whitespace was replaced with `%20`.

Comment: PHP sees the rewritten URL, not the original. You need to test `$_GET['cat']`.

Comment: @Barmar I've tested $_Get... It's not it.

Comment: Why do people keep writing PHP like this?

Answer (score 1):

verify the spaces I'm not sure they allowed in urls

Have a look to the documentation :

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

try this :

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['cat'];
if(isset($page)) {
switch($page) {
case "index":
$title = "this is homepage";
break;
case "a":
$title = "products";
break;
case "b":
$title = "services";
break;
}
}else{
$title = "default title";
}

print "<title>$title</title>";
?>
```

Comment: my htaccess it's fine, I use "-"... it was just an example. The code for changing the title is not working for pages

Comment: @OlivierSoulet now i use this, so it should take only the page i need but still is not working: $path=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$page=basename($path);
if(isset($page)) {
switch($page)....

Comment: have you tried to display what is in $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?
Try a var_dump of this var

Comment: @OlivierSoulet you mean "var_dump($_SERVER)" ? ... i get a lot of things like:    ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(33) "/home/dany/public_html/mysite.com" ... ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(11) "cat=contact" ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(11) "cat=contact" ..... ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(12) "/contact.php" ....["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(12) "/contact.php" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(43) "/home/dany/public_html/mysite.com/index.php" ... ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(10) "/index.php" ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1375259963) ["argv"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "cat=contact" } ["argc"]=> int(1) } ?>

Comment: @Freelancer you mean "var_dump($_SERVER)" ? ... i get a lot of things like: ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(33) "/home/dany/public_html/mysite.com" ... ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(11) "cat=contact" ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(11) "cat=contact" ..... ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(12) "/contact.php" ....["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(12) "/contact.php" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(43) "/home/dany/public_html/mysite.com/index.php" ... ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(10) "/index.php"

Comment: ok so, this is what there is inside your $_SERVER, as you can see at the index ['PHP_SELF'] there is no 'page-1.php' but index.php, php see only what is rewritten. I assume you're on your page contact ? So as Barmar said you have to test your $_GET['cat'] and to test on what there is inside not on the name of your pages

Comment: @Continental I added an example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use \s in you rewrite rule instead of space:

```
RewriteRule ^page\s1.php$ index.php?cat=a [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\s2.php$ index.php?cat=b [NC]
```